# Chinese manhua about selling cheap stuff from Earth in a cultivation world

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

I wanted to find out the title of a manhua about a guy who can travel between Earth and a cultivation world.

In that world, common items from Earth become expensive (for example, a simple grass becomes legendary material, or a flu medicine becomes an elixir). The main character received the highest membership from a famous auction shop because of this.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: I read it on manganato.net

Comment: After days after days of searching, I finally found it. The title is "I Scared the Divine Lord as I Handed over the Ancient Immortal Pill".

Answer (score 1):

The title is "I Scared the Divine Lord as I Handed over the Ancient Immortal Pill".

> Bai Yifan has an ancient ring that allows him to travel freely between the Earth and the fantasy world, and he has discovered that "plants and animals" on the Earth will evolve into treasures when they are taken to the fantasy world. An apple evolves into an immortal fruit, an egg will hatch into a phoenix or an earth dog has the bloodline of a dragon. One could even use tobacco to manipulate the enemy to their advantage.

Comment: Well done for finding what you were looking for. We'd be grateful if you could mark your answer as accepted by clicking on the green check-mark beneath the voting buttons